# React navigation 5, hide bottom tab bar on second stack screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on an app which has a stack navigation and a bottom tab navigation, I need to show the bottom tab bar in first stack screen but not in second one. here's my code for navigations:

```js
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTab.Navigator>
        <BottomTab.Screen name='StackNavigation' component={StackNavigation} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='home' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='SecondTab' component={SecondTab} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='shoppingBag' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='Offers' component={Offers} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='discount' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='profile' {...props} />,
        }} />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

and here's my stack navigation:

```js
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CardDetails} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="OfficeDetails" component={OfficeDetails} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

this code is working but only for first stack navigation and for OfficeDetails page I need to hide my tab bar. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `BottomTabNavigator` navigator as a component to `StackNavigationWithTabs` and export `StackNavigationWithoutTabs` by default.

```js
const StackNavigationWithTabs= createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigationWithTabs= () => {
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CardDetails} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
   
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
      <BottomTab.Navigator>
        <BottomTab.Screen name='StackNavigationWithTabs' component={StackNavigationWithTabs} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='home' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='SecondTab' component={SecondTab} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='shoppingBag' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='Offers' component={Offers} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='discount' {...props} />,
        }} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} options={{
          tabBarButton: (props) => <BottomTabStyle label='profile' {...props} />,
        }} />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
   
  )
}
```

```js
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigationWithoutTabs= () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator.Navigator>
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="BottomTabNavigator" component= {BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <StackNavigator.Screen name="OfficeDetails" component={OfficeDetails} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </StackNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this solution will remove tab bar from first stack screen (CardDetails) as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check and let me know about this approach.

Comment: two stack navigation is the key of this lock. thank you.